# Android Node.js Socket.io always connecting successful

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I want to make communication with between pc and Android using Socket.io.   Code:

http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Boolean socketConnection;
TextView tw;
Socket mSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000");
        mSocket.connect();
        socketConnection = true;
        tw.setText("Yes");
    }catch(URISyntaxException ex) {
        socketConnection = false;
        tw.setText("No");
    }

}
```

When I'm debugging application; server application albeit closed, client says connected successful. And when I'm opening server application, server application can't see client.

Comment: But you're connecting to `localhost:3000` on the Android device, which would be somewhere on the Android device

Comment: Sounds like everything is working as expected. What is your question?

Comment: Because I'm using android emulator on pc. @Patosai

Comment: And i'm tried "http://192.168.1.5:3000" but, same again.

Comment: I'm solved problem; mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code, as @Patosai has pointed out, is that you are connecting to `localhost:3000`.  This means that you are attempting to connect to the device (the Android phone or simulator) which is running your application.  This will always say that it is connected since a device can always connect with itself.

Assuming that you are connected to the same network as your PC, you will need to find your PC's IP address and the port you have chosen for communication.  For example, if your determined your PC's IP was `123.456.2.1` and the port you have in your Socket.IO code is `4000` you would write `mSocket = IO.socket("http://123.456.2.1:4000")`